# Can we create single Storyboard for Multiple buttons in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ButtonEffect_01" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="btnAdd">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="#FFF3FF00"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Width="69" Height="27">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ButtonEffect_01}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

I have 3 More Buttons btnDelete, btnUpdate, btnBack can i use same Storyboard for all these buttons? Any binding method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid specifying the target you can define your storyboard inside the `Style` of the `Button`s:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="#FFF3FF00"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can share animation to multiple objects,but a check of animation status is needed.
For prevent errors you can stop animation before assign new target:

```
private void MouseEnter(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonEffect_01.Stop();
        ButtonEffect_01.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, (sender as Button).Name);
        ButtonEffect_01.Begin();
    }
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn376886.aspx

Comment: The storyboard have to run for each button at the same time so I don't think you can do this...

Comment: Yes the cost of use a single instance of a storyboard is that,only one animation at  time. But if the scope is drop a shadow on mouse enter i think he have a single animation running at time.

Comment: Hmm..You're right, it would be better to stop first animation on mouse leve, or start a new one...;)

Comment: Yes seems logical to me too but sometimes one has to cope with strange requirements. Anyway you get my +1 :)